# API with Lumen Framework authorize not work

Tags: php, laravel, api, jwt, lumen

I working a simple API with Lumen, But I encounter a problem. I want to delete the user if he is the user, but my authorize is not work.

For the login I use JWT token.

UserController.php

```
    /**
     * Delete user by user id.
     *
     * @param int $id
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function delete($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);

        $this->authorize('delete', $user);

        $user->delete();

        return response()->json([
            'success'   =>  'User deleted with success'
        ], 200);
    }
```

UserPolicy.php

```
class UserPolicy
{

    public function delete(User $user, User $user_current)
    {
        return $user->id === $user_current->id;
    }

}
```

AuthServiceProvider.php

```
    public function boot()
    {
        Gate::policy(User::class, UserPolicy::class);

        $this->app['auth']->viaRequest('api', function ($request) {
            if ($request->header('Authorization')) {
                return User::where('api_token', $request->input('api_token'))->first();
            }
        });
    }
```

I I do not understand why it does not work.

Comment: Could you put your errors here?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help, 
Here is the message that but send back : {
    "error": "Token not provided."
}

Comment: Are you sending **Authorization** in header of your post data?

Comment: Yes look here : [link](https://i.ibb.co/nzKnRZ2/Capture.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using like below in your header:

```
Authorization : Bearer [TOKEN]
```

---

Update 1:

If you're in Apache, I guess this might help you as it works on mine:
Just add these lines on your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)  
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

---

Update 2:

Okay, Please change your AuthServiceProvider like below codes:

```
$this->app['auth']->viaRequest('api', function ($request) {
    $token = $request->bearerToken();

    if(!$token) {
        // Unauthorized response if token not there
        throw new Exception('token not provided');
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: Always the same message.

Comment: :'( Not work, I have the impression the problem comes from the code, right?

Comment: Are you using passport library?

Comment: No, I using firebase/php-jwt, but my API not work whan I add authorize action

Comment: It does not fit in the condition.

Comment: OK, I added token property in params and he return this error : [link](https://ibb.co/d0q9R4m)

Comment: No, you don't need to set in params, only on headers, just like: `Authorization : Bearer eyJ0eXAi.......`

Comment: OK, Thank you very mach for your help, I resolved my problem, I juste forget to pass the good api token and renamed the params in token and using Bearer token.